# Get curl error description in bash script?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a few cron jobs that run and rely on curl to do some actions. If they fail, I send myself a mail with the curl exit code. To figure out what went wrong, I then query the curl exit code and wind up on this page: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html.

Is there a way in my bash script to look up the error description and send myself that instead of just an error code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy all of those error messages into your bash script as an array:

```
curl_codes=(
  "All fine. Proceed as usual."
  "The URL you passed to libcurl used a protocol that this libcurl does not support."
  "Something else")

[ $exit_code -eq 0 ] || echo "Error $exit_code: ${curl_codes[$exit_code]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `--log-file` flag to create a log file and then to parse this log. This is what I do [in this script](https://github.com/laurent22/rsync-time-backup/blob/master/rsync_tmbackup.sh), in particular see below the `grep` commands I'm using to lookup for error messages.

```
if [ -n "$(grep "rsync error:" "$LOG_FILE")" ]; then
    # Handle errors
elif [ -n "$(grep "rsync:" "$LOG_FILE")" ]; then
    # Handle warnings
fi
```

Comment: Rather than using `if [ -n "$(grep)" ]`, it would be better to use `if grep -q`